# list union with duplicates

Tags: python

I need to unite two lists in Python3,where duplicates can exist,and for one set of these the resulting list will contain as many as max in both lists.An example might clarify it:

```
[1,2,2,5]( some operator)[2,5,5,5,9]=[1,2,2,5,5,5,9]
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects) class:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> combined = Counter([1,2,2,5]) | Counter([2,5,5,5,9])
>>> list(combined.elements())
[1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 9]
```

It functions as a multiset (an unordered collection where each element can appear multiple times). The `|` operator gives you the union of the multisets, where each element appears max(apperances_in_counter1, appearances_in_counter2) times.

This class was added in Python 2.7 and 3.1.

Comment: nice...I didn't know that module.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that one. Since the term "multiset" sounds like a total buzzword to me, let me quote its description from Python docs: **"A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects."** I find this description more intuitive, I hope you will too.

Answer (score 2):

Why use lists in the first place? That data looks like a dict to me:

```
[1,2,2,5] -> {1: 1, 2: 2, 5: 1}
[2,5,5,5,9] -> {2: 1, 5: 3, 9: 1}
```

Then it's simple:

```
keys = set(a.keys()+b.keys())
vals = [max(a.get(n, 0), b.get(n, 0)) for n in keys]
d = dict(zip(keys, vals))
print d
```

Result:

> {1: 1, 2: 2, 5: 3, 9: 1}

Comment: Update: following @interjay's answer, you get essentially the same data model, but already implemented with methods to operate on it. Go for that solution!

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert arrays to dictionaries with `a[key] = count`
2. Create new dictionary with rules `c[key] = a.get(key, 0) > b.get(key, 0) and a[key] or b[key]`. You need to iterate through both keys in a and in b dicts.
3. Expand dictionary, `result += [value] * key`