# LINQ Union with duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say we have the following three lists:

```
{ 1, 2, 2, 3 }
{ 2, 3, 3, 4 }
{ 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5 }
```

How can we then convert the above to a list having each item repeated the maximum number of times it's found in a list.i.e.,

```
{1, 2, 2 (Found twice in list 1), 3, 3 (Twice in list 2), 4, 5, 5, 5 (Thrice in list 3)}
```

I can achieve the above through loops, however, I am looking for a LINQ method that might already be there.

The question is similar to [list union with duplicates in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430934/list-union-with-duplicates)

Comment: You basically answered your question. So what have you tried that didn't worked out?

Comment: What did you try to achieve this? Show your code. Anyway I don´t really understand your question. Where is 1 a max. in *any* of the three lists?

Comment: following your explanations, your result has no sense? could you detail your logic?

Comment: @Frenchy the max quantity of 1 is 1 (first list). The max quantity of 2 is 2 (first list).  The max quantity of 3 is 2 (second list). and so on

Comment: @Frenchy, Reniuz and HimBromBeere please have a look at the updated question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linq in one line

```
int[][] items = { new[]{ 1, 2, 2, 3 }, new[] { 2, 3, 3, 4 }, new[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5 } };
var result = items.SelectMany(x => x.GroupBy(y => y)).GroupBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Count()).First()).SelectMany(x => x);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/kZhseg

Comment: Here is an extension method forked from the above fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/WdizYg

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
var xs = new [] { 1, 2, 2, 3 };
var ys = new [] { 2, 3, 3, 4 };
var zs = new [] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5 };

var result =
    xs
        .ToLookup(x => x)
        .Concat(ys.ToLookup(x => x))
        .Concat(zs.ToLookup(x => x))
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
        .Select(x => new { x.Key, count = x.Max(y => y.Count()) })
        .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x.Key, x.count));
```

It gives the result you want.